# How to search for "SELECT * FROM" in Aptana?

Tags: aptana

How can you search for SELECT * FROM in aptana? If you search for that, it just finds every SELECT FROM, taking the * as a wildcard, if you quote it, it doesn't find any of them, wildcards before and after quotes, also doesn't work, so, how can you do this?

You never should use SELECT * FROM, it's not good, since table can change and your code gets screwed, so I'm trying to fix this, but the project is too big, and Aptana search is not helping at all. If I can't do it in Aptana, what's a work around?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the text to a different text editor and put full string in quotations.  Try single quotations.